# GORM bidirectional One-to-Many

Tags: grails, grails-orm

I'm trying to create a bidirectional one-to-many relationship between Foo and Bar domains in GORM.

Here's what I have so far:

```
class Bar {
   static belongsTo = [foo: Foo]
}

class Foo {
   Set bars = []
   static hasMany = [bars: Bar]
}
```

The problem that I'm having is when I go to use the relationship methods, they don't seem to behave the way that I think they should.  For example, you would think a statement like "foo.bars.add(bar)" would also set the foo field on the bar argument.  But when I call "bar.foo.id" I'm told that the foo field is null.  I can fix that problem if I use "bar.foo = foo" instead of "foo.bars.add(bar)".  Unfortunately, when I call "foo.bars.size()" it tells me that it is 0.

To get a clearer picture of what I'm talking about, here are my tests:

```
def testFoo() {
   def foo = new Foo()
   def bar = new Bar()

   foo.bars.add(bar)

   println "foo.bars.size() = ${foo.bars.size()}"
   println "bar.id = ${bar.id}"

   for(def xbar : foo.bars) {
      println "bar.id = ${xbar.id}"
   }

   println "foo.id = ${foo.id}"
   println "bar.foo.id = ${bar?.foo?.id}" // <- is null
}

def testBar() {
   def foo = new Foo()
   def bar = new Bar()

   bar.foo = foo

   println "foo.bars.size() = ${foo.bars.size()}" // <- is 0
   println "bar.id = ${bar.id}"

   for(def xbar : foo.bars) {
      println "bar.id = ${xbar.id}"
   }

   println "foo.id = ${foo.id}"
   println "bar.foo.id = ${bar?.foo?.id}"
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Note: I'm running this through an integration test.  I've also found that "foo.addToBars(bar)" works the way that I think "foo.bars.add(bar)" and "bar.foo = foo" should work.

**Update** Here's a quick hack I did that does what I want (using Hibernate and JPA):

```
import java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException;
import java.lang.reflect.Method;
import java.util.LinkedList;

import stuff.Foo;

public class MyList<Bar> extends LinkedList {

   private Foo foo;

   public MyList(Foo foo) {
      this.foo = foo;
   }

   @Override
   public boolean add(Object obj) {
      boolean result = super.add(obj);

      try {
         Method barMethod = obj.getClass().getDeclaredMethod("setFoo", Foo.class);
         barMethod.invoke(obj, foo);
      }
      catch(NoSuchMethodException noSuchMethod) {
         noSuchMethod.printStackTrace();
      }
      catch(InvocationTargetException invocationTarget) {
         invocationTarget.printStackTrace();
      }
      catch(IllegalAccessException illegalAccess) {
         illegalAccess.printStackTrace();
      }

      return result;
   }
}
```

Comment: I tried the same "experiment" using Hibernate and JPA, but got the same results.

From a Java perspective, I can understand that the Container holding the many elements doesn't know how to set the value on the other side of the relationship. (ie. bar.foo = foo)

From a database perspective, however, this doesn't make any sense.  When I call "foo.bars", doesn't it also execute the SQL query "SELECT * FROM Bar WHERE foo_id = :foo_id"?  And if that's the case, then the bar object's foo field must be set.  But it isn't.  And yet, foo.bars contains the bar.

Answer (score 2):

If you [read the documentation](http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/GORM.html#oneToMany), you'll learn that, as you found out but are still questioning, the correct way to add items to a collection so they are persisted correctly is to use the `addTo*` methods.

So in your case, when you said that using `addToBars` worked, that's the right way to do this.  That said, there are some performance hits you take with that.  Another way is to do:

```
bar.foo = foo
bar.save()
```

The downside is that foo will not contain bar in its existing Set.  You'd have to pull it from the database again.  It's a bit of a give and take and you just use the best method for your situation.

Comment: Where does the documentation say that the addTo* method is the correct way to add an item to a collection? The documentation for addTo* only says that it will set both sides of the bi-directional relationship.

Comment: Yes, which is to say that if you want both sides set, that is what you are supposed to do.